# Adding Credit Card Payment Support to my website

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I've puzzled by this question for quite a while, but never had the need for it. Now I do.

What I currently need is a Credit Card payment option for my website that does not rely on services such as Paypal. I want something like Name.com or Hostmonster.com have. You simply enter you credit card number, expiration date and the three little numbers at the back of the card. How can I achieve the same effect on my website?

I'll be programming the website in PHP.

Answers would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly "that does not rely on services such as Paypal"?

Comment: You will need some kind of credit card service to validate and accept the payments. Also, there are strict regulations for credit card input on websites. By the sound of it, you're not ready for that. Some of those payment providers support better integration in your website, so it *looks like* a customer is entering their information on your site.

Comment: you must have tieup with banks...

Comment: You will need to obtain a "merchant" account at one of the payment gateway providers and most of these guys are "banks" and a few others like stripe, paypay, google, etc.

Comment: Also Braintree is good.  Or Balanced for marketplaces.

Comment: You will need a merchant account with an inline service provider. Something like sagepay. It may look like everything is processed on a website but a lot of the time it has been transferred to a secure server and skinned

Comment: Any payment method where the customer enters credit card numbers (with or without the CVV2 code) _on your site_ will be subject to PCI-DSS rules and regulations. Gearing up to pass a PCI-DSS audit can be quite expensive (it's a lot more than simply being under SSL). Plus, merchant accounts/payment gateways still charge monthly fees plus a percentage of the sales. If you are high volume, ma/pg may work out to be cheaper than using an offsite Third Party payment system such as PayPal; otherwise, stick with an offsite Third Party processor.

Comment: Card data can be entered *on your site* without falling into PCI scope as long as it doesn't get transmitted *to your server*. That's the use case behind Braintree, Stripe, and whatever PayPal's competing product is called this week (among others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to signup to a payment gateway. It's a service that allows you to process credit card payments. I know you don't want to use PayPAL to accept payments, but PayPAL offer two solutions:

1. PayPAL Payments - That is the button and people pay through PayPAL
2. PayPAL Payments Pro (Payment Gateway). That is when you use PHP or anything else to connect to PayPAL with the credit card information. The customer never knows you used PayPAL, and they never leave your site.

When choosing a payment gateway these are the four most important things you should consider:

1. How easy is it to implement (PayPAL has a lot of documentation)
2. How much is the monthly fee.
3. How much do they charge per transaction.
4. How much do they charge to setup an account.

There are other options, and one of the most common is Authorize.net, but the is more setting up and a larger deposit to open an account.

Most accounts will require a background and credit check.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'll still need to rely on a Merchant Services company for card processing.  There are many companies that boast an API that can then be accessed with PHP.  One that I have recently learned of is [Stripe](http://stripe.com).  However, there are many competitors and you can research other companies further, but companies like Stripe will allow you to generate payments programmatically without having to leave your site to visit the black-box that is PayPal.